# Shift the records in Pandas DataFrame with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with shifting pandas record's position with specific conditions.
What I want to do is to move every row that has a value in its before_id(it includes String) column into the next index place of another row whose value in node_id(it includes String) is same as it.
And my code didn't work as my expectation. It returned no error but didn't sort them at all.

I'm a little bit worried about my explain though ....
Do you have any idea to achieve this ?? or Is it impossible to do in Pandas ??

```
client_data = """node_id,option,before_id
    1aa,A,
    8xyz,C,2aa
    2aa,A,1aa
    5mm,A,4bb
    4bb,C,8xyz
    6ccc,5mm,
    7,C,6ccc       
    """


df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(client_data), dtype='string', error_bad_lines=False)
    before = pd.notnull(df['before_id'])
    for ind,row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.notnull(row[2]):
            before_id = row[2]
            before_ind = df.index[df['node_id']==before_id]
            next_ind = before_ind + 1
            row.reindex(index=next_ind)
        else:
            pass
```

```
df

node_id,option,before_id
1aa,A,
8xyz,C,2aa
2aa,A,1aa
5mm,A,4bb
4bb,C,8xyz
6ccc,5mm,
7,C,6ccc


ideal output 

node_id,option,before_id
1aa,A,
2aa,A,1aa
8xyz,C,2aa
4bb,C,8xyz
5mm,A,4bb
6ccc,5mm,
7,C,6ccc
```

Comment: Your example is complicated and ambiguous. Can you please provide a minimal example with only unique numbers or single letters to make your logic clear? For instance how is the `5` of the second row changed into `2xxx`?

Comment: How is the `5` of the second row changed into `2xxx`, but the`8` in the third one is not changed into `1aa`?

Comment: Thank you for commenting , I wrote it wrong by mistake . I already edit the df and deleted duplicates. Does it look ok ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears that you are trying to solve a depth-first search graph problem.
Below solution is using networkx graph library.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

x = '''node_id,option,before_id
1aa,A,
8xyz,C,2aa
2aa,A,1aa
5mm,A,4bb
4bb,C,8xyz
6ccc,5mm,
7,C,6ccc'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x))
print("Original\n",df)
print('--------------\n')

import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'before_id', 'node_id', 'option')
sortedNodes = [n[1] for n in list(nx.dfs_edges(G))]

df.node_id = df.node_id.astype('category')
df.node_id.cat.set_categories(sortedNodes, inplace=True)
df = df.sort_values(['node_id'])
print("Node-sorted\n",df)
```

Output:

```
Original
   node_id option before_id
0     1aa      A       NaN
1    8xyz      C       2aa
2     2aa      A       1aa
3     5mm      A       4bb
4     4bb      C      8xyz
5    6ccc    5mm       NaN
6       7      C      6ccc
--------------

Node-sorted
   node_id option before_id
0     1aa      A       NaN
2     2aa      A       1aa
1    8xyz      C       2aa
4     4bb      C      8xyz
3     5mm      A       4bb
5    6ccc    5mm       NaN
6       7      C      6ccc
```

Comment: Also, python 3.9 has built-in graphlib library which might provide same capabilities as networkx. You can check it out at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works without any error but it returns the different output from yours . Maybe as you said , it depends on my Python version, 3.8. I will check the docs out.